# I am getting invaid CIDR error for my terraform configuration while adding security group

Tags: terraform

The error I am getting is

```
Error: "\"10.0.1.0/24\",\"10.0.2.0/24\"" is not a valid CIDR block: invalid CIDR address: "10.0.1.0/24","10.0.2.0/24"

  on security_group.tf line 36, in resource "aws_security_group" "firstVPCPrivateVMSG":
  36: resource "aws_security_group" "firstVPCPrivateVMSG"{
```

My VPC is 10.0.0.0/16

Below is Security group block

```
resource "aws_security_group" "firstVPCPrivateVMSG"{
vpc_id = aws_vpc.firstVPC.id
name = "firstVPCPrivateVMSG"

ingress {
    description = "Allow ssh connections from VMs in Public Subnet"
    protocol = "tcp"
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 22
    cidr_blocks = [join(",", [for s in var.public_cidrs: format("\"%s\"",s)]),join(",", [for s in 
    var.private_cidrs: format("\"%s\"",s)])]
}
```

Comment: variable.tf looks like below

variable "vpc_cidr" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "public_cidrs" {
  type = list
  default = ["10.0.1.0/24","10.0.2.0/24"]
}

variable "private_cidrs" {
  type = list
  default = ["10.0.3.0/24","10.0.4.0/24"]
}

Comment: Your Terraform code there is jumbled and won't run but the issue looks to be with how you are handling the list of CIDRs. `join` turns a list into a string when `cidr_blocks` wants a list. Just remove that and the surrounding `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making one array of two strings, when you want an array with all your cidrs combined. Just use `concat`:

```
ingress {
  description = "Allow ssh connections from VMs in Public Subnet"
  protocol = "tcp"
  from_port = 0
  to_port = 22
  cidr_blocks = concat(var.public_cidrs, var.private_cidrs)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. That's exactly what I did after I posted this query and it worked :-).

Still left this posted here for more alternatives